# Customize theme font color

Tags: themes, customize

I am using the distinguished theme. I want to set the main font color to something more dark, how could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `describe-face` to get the name of the face at point.

And you can change the color with `custom-set-faces`.

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(default ((t (:foreground "khaki4" :slant italic)))))
```